# JSON data changing when decoded flutter

Tags: json, string, flutter, decode, rapidapi

My app fetches data from TikTok through a API. The username and caption of some TikToks contains some special characters and fonts like: ℋℒℰ and some contains text in other languages. When I tested the API on its website it show the data correct:

[image]

but when I get that data through my app it changes the special characters and language to something like this

ÐÐµ ÑÐ¾ÑÐµÐ»Ð° Ð¸Ð³ÑÐ°ÑÑ Ñ Ð±Ð°ÑÐ½Ð¸ÑÑÐ¾Ð¼ ÐÐµÐ»Ð¸ÐºÐ¾Ð»ÐµÐ¿Ð½Ð°Ñ ÑÐºÑÐ¸Ð¿Ð°ÑÐºÐ°!

and other values or links that is in English does not change.

The code am using is:

```
Map<String, String> headers = {
  "X-RapidAPI-Host":
      "tiktok-downloader-download-tiktok-videos-without-watermark.p.rapidapi.com",
  "X-RapidAPI-Key": "-------------------------------",
};

final body = {'url': url};
final uri = Uri.https(
    "tiktok-downloader-download-tiktok-videos-without-watermark.p.rapidapi.com",
    '/vid/index',
    body);
final response = await http.get(
  uri,
  headers: headers,
);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
  print(data['description'][0]);
}
```

The API am using

https://rapidapi.com/maatootz/api/tiktok-downloader-download-tiktok-videos-without-watermark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works bad with cyrillic letters

Try this

```
json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes))
```

Comment: I don't know who but that works, Thanks!